# AngularJS - Auto update data from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

**Ctrl 1**

```
$scope.$watch(function () {return svc.getMessage();}, function (messageBody) {
    if(messageBody){

        var eventName = data.eventName;
        var someCtrl = $rootScope.$new();
        $controller('someCtrl', {$scope: someCtrl});

        // For add user event 
        if (eventName == "EVENT_USER_ADDED") {
            someCtrl.addUserEventAction();
        }
    }

    svc.clearMessage();
});
```

**Ctrl 2**

```
$scope.addUserEventAction = function () { 
    var userTreeViewCtrl = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('userTreeViewCtrl', {
        $scope: userTreeViewCtrl
    });
    userTreeViewCtrl.ReloadUserList();
};
```

**Ctrl 3**

```
$scope.initUserTreeView = function () {
    $scope.treeLength = 0;
    userModuleService.getUserTreeView(usertId, siteId)
    .then(function (data) {
        $scope.tree = data;
        if (data !== undefined) {
            $scope.treeLength = $scope.tree.length;
        } else {
            $scope.treeLength = 0;
        }
    });
};

$scope.initUserTreeView();


$scope.ReloadUserList = function(){
    $scope.initUserTreeView();
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="treeLength > 0">
    <div ng-repeat="user in tree">
        <li class="pointer"><a>{{user.name}}</a></li>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user is added from admin, the application receives a popup message with event name `EVENT_USER_ADDED`. Based on that, I am updating user list html dynamically and fetching latest records.

How do I dynamically update user list when a new user is added or deleted ?

Comment: Have you read about broadcasting in AngularJS? Your solution is very complicated. I could deliver you a solution based on broadcasting but not that kind of message service you like to implement.

Comment: @lin: The messaging service is working well. And I tried placing a link where user can update user list clicking on it. The only thing is the html is not auto updating. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Yea, because its not working as you expect. The message service you implement is custom and not working that way. `$controller('userTreeViewCtrl', { ...` is initalizing a new controller instance. It does not initialize the controller used in your HTML View. So your `$scopes` binded in your view will not be updated, because its an other instance. You need to inject kind of singleton pattern in your controller hierarchy. Or just use the common way in AngularJS like broadcasting.

Comment: @lin, thanks for shedding light on what is happening in core. Could you please post snippet related to above code. Or how do I inject singleton pattern in controller hierarchy or broadcast method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the common way of AngularJS by using the `$broadcast`system. Your example is not working because `$controller('userTreeViewCtrl', { ...` is initalizing a new controller instance. It does not initialize the controller used in your HTML View. So your `$scopes` binded in your view will not be updated, because its an other instance.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <a ng-click="sendData()">Send Data</a>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ListenController">
    <span ng-bind="data"></span>
</div>
```

#### Controllers

```
/**
 * Test controller
 */
angular.module('app')
    .controller('TestController', [
        '$scope',
        '$rootScope',
        function ($scope, $rootScope) {
            $scope.sendData = function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('myEvent', 'someData')
            };
        }
    ]);

/**
 * Listen controller
 */
angular.module('app')
    .controller('ListenController', [
        '$rootScope',
        function ($rootScope) {

            $scope.data = '';

            $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function (event, data) {
                $scope.data = data;
                alert($scope.data);
            })
        }
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the posted answer, but how can I use existing  $controller('userTreeViewCtrl', { ... instance.and use in HTML view, so my $scopes gets bind in my view ?

Comment: Added an example with scopes and views. It should be clear how to implement this logic in your application, isnt it?

Comment: That will work in all cases. But considering John Papa's statement - `Consider using $scope in a controller only when needed. For example when publishing and subscribing events using $emit, $broadcast, or $on consider moving these uses to a factory and invoke from the controller.` The best practice would be switching ot use of factories in such cases or moving the usage of $emit, $broadcast, or $on to a factory ? Assume I want to update values in a controller on certain broadcasts, If I move those $on's to a factory, I'm wondering how to inform the controller again.

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy Is this a new question? I think your problem is solved with my solution.

Comment: Its not a new question but the matter of discussion is the best possible solution to implement. Also does this broadcast method works with new window as well? What changes one must do to observe event changes in new window ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy still no feedback?